# Resolving dependant template type without this-> or RealType::

Tags: c++, templates

I'll begin with some code.  Consider:

```
template <typename Message> void ProcessMessage (const Message& msg)
{
    const uint32_t value = msg.mValue.GetValAs <uint32_t>();
}
```

Here, the type of `mValue` is different for different `Message` types.  All of the types it could be have a member template function `GetValAs` and a member `mValue` -- these are invariant conditions.  `Message` could be something like:

```
class Message16
{
public:
    Message16 (uint16_t value) : mValue (value) {}; 
    UInt16Field mValue;
};
```

Where `UInt16Field` is a concrete instantiation of a class template.

Or it could be:

```
class Message32
{
public:
    Message32 (uint32_t value) : mValue (value) {}; 
    std::string mFoo;
    double mBar;
    UInt32Field mValue;
};
```

Where `UIInt32Field` is another concrete instantiation of the same class template.

Now the problem here is resolution of dependant names, in particular:

```
template <typename Message> void ProcessMessage (const Message& msg)
{
    const uint32_t value = msg.mValue.GetValAs <uint32_t>();
}
```

yields compiler error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void ProcessMessage(const Message&)’:
main.cpp:60:57: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
main.cpp:60:59: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

OK, this is normally straightforward enough...  I'd simply use `this->` or `RealType::` to resolve the dependant name.  Such as with:

```
    const uint32_t value = msg.mValue.UInt16Field::GetValAs <uint32_t>();
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This works fine so long as `mValue` is always a `UInt16Field` -- but it's not.  It could be (almost) anything.  If I try to call `ProcessMessage` with a `Message32` for example:

```
const uint32_t u32 = 32;
Message32 msg32 (u32);
ProcessMessage (msg32);
```

I get some expected (and admittedly not great) compiler errors:

```
error: ‘GetValAs<uint32_t>’ is not a member of ‘const UInt32Field {aka const IntegralField<unsigned int>}’
```

So, the question is...

How can I bring in the dependant type of `mValue` here:

```
    const uint32_t value = msg.mValue.GetValAs <uint32_t>();
```

Without using `this->` (since there is no `this`) or `RealType::` (since I don't know the `RealType`)?

---

Here is a complete testbed, short as I could make it:

```
template <typename IntegralType>
class BasicField
{
public:
    BasicField (IntegralType val) : mValue (val) {}
    IntegralType mValue;
};

template <typename IntegralType>
class IntegralField
:
    public BasicField <IntegralType>
{
public:
    IntegralField (IntegralType val)
    :
        BasicField <IntegralType> (val*2)
    {
    }

    IntegralType GetVal () const
    {
        return this->mValue/2;
    }

    operator IntegralType () const
    {
        return GetVal();
    }

    template <typename As> As GetValAs () const
    {
        return static_cast <As> (GetVal());
    }
};

typedef IntegralField <uint16_t> UInt16Field;
typedef IntegralField <uint32_t> UInt32Field;

class Message16
{
public:
    Message16 (uint16_t value) : mValue (value) {};
    UInt16Field mValue;
};

class Message32
{
public:
    Message32 (uint32_t value) : mValue (value) {};
    std::string mFoo;
    double mBar;
    UInt32Field mValue;
};

template <typename Message> void ProcessMessage (const Message& msg)
{
    const uint32_t value = msg.mValue.GetValAs <uint32_t>();
}

int main()
{
    const uint16_t u16 = 16;
    Message16 msg16 (u16);
    ProcessMessage (msg16);

    const uint32_t u32 = 32;
    Message32 msg32 (u32);
    ProcessMessage (msg32);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to explain to the compiler that `GetValAs` is a template, try:

```
msg.mValue.template GetValAs<uint32_t>();
```

Comment: Well, I'll be dipped.

Comment: And I tried this, too; only in the wrong place:  `template msg.mValue.GetValAs<uint32_t>();`

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
 msg.mValue.template GetValAs <uint32_t>();
```

That is the syntax. The explanation is similar as that for `typename`.

Combining `typename` and `template`, sometime code looks like this:

```
 using type = typename X<T>::template get<U>::type;
```

Or if you use typedef, then:

```
 typedef typename X<T>::template get<U>::type type;
```

I've such monster in my code.

Comment: +1, @DanielFrey beat you by 8 seconds.  Regarding `type`, you of course have a `typedef` in `get`, I assume?  This I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: @JohnDibling: No, even with typedef, you need `typename` and `template`. So code would be this: `typedef typename X<T>::template get<U>::type type;`.

Comment: Sure, right.  But what I mean is, without that `typedef` in the `get`, `get<U>::type` doesn't mean anything.  See what I'm saying?  I'd prefer to avoid adding a `typedef` to `get`.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Yes, but it could be class as well, something like `struct type {... }`. But that doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 2):

```
const uint32_t value = msg.mValue.template GetValAs <uint32_t>();
                                  ^^^^^^^^
```

`GetValAs` is a template and compiler should knows it.